# Return only pattern matched string from grep

Tags: grep

Is it possible to search and print only the matched pattern from grep. The default action is to print the whole line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use the `-o` option, e.g.,

```
$ echo 'hello wide world' | grep -o wide
wide
```